# How to call a function with parameters action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

im trying to make a function that will be used in multiple projects and save , load or display a high score table depending on the parameters entered. my current code is

```
function test(action:String):void {
    if (action == "loadHS") {
        trace("loading")
    } else if (action == "save") {
        trace("saveinghs")
    } else if (action == null) {
        trace("please provide an operation for high score table")
    } else {
        trace(" the action" + action + "is not a valid action");
    }
}

test(loadHS);
```

witch creates the following compiler error.

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 14  1120: Access of undefined property loadHS.
```

what am i doing wrong? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable **loadHS** is not yet *defined*.  This means it is *declared*, but you need to give it a value to *define* it.

`var loadHS:String = "loadHS";`

Comment: changed code to
var action:String

function test(action:String):void {
 if (action == "loadHS") {
  trace("loading")
 } else if (action == "save") {
  trace("saveinghs")
 } else if (action == null) {
  trace("please provide an operation for high score table")
 } else {
  trace(" the action" + action + "is not a valid action");
 }
}

test(action = "loadHS");
witch fixed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes to [define a String literal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html).

```
test("loadHS");
```

Without quotes, ActionScript is expecting to find a `variable` that you've created named `loadHS`.